# NamingStrategy when Deserializing object using Custom Contract Resolver with Json.Net

Tags: json.net, deserialization

I am using a custom contract resolver along with JsonProperty.

Here is my class

```
public class Foo {
  [JsonProperty('id')]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty('fullname')]
  public int FullName { get; set; }
}
```

and have a custom contract resolver like so

```
    public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public bool UsePropertyName { get; }

        public CustomContractResolver(bool useJsonPropertyName)
        {
            NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(true, true);
            UsePropertyName = useJsonPropertyName;
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            if (!UsePropertyName)
                property.PropertyName = property.UnderlyingName;

            return property;
        }
    }
```

But when i deserialize my json, the naming strategy is not applied with this custom contract resolver.

Note that this contract resolver is initialized in the Startup class of a dotnet core app and not passed as a param when deserializing.

Thanks for all the help :)